# AspNet Core - [Required] attribute not working on file input

Tags: asp.net-core

I have an AspNet Core web app with a simple view to allow the user to upload a file.
The file property in the view model has a [Required] attribute. However, clicking the submit button will perform a post even if there is no file selected.

View Model:

```
public class DocumentUploadViewModel
{
    [HiddenInput]
    public string Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [FileExtensions(Extensions = "pdf")]
    public IFormFile Document { get; set; }
}
```

View:

```
@using App.Models.DocumentViewModels
@model DocumentUploadViewModel

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Upload Document";
}

<h2>Upload Document</h2>

<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" asp-controller="Document" asp-action="Upload" >
    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <div class="form-group">
            <input asp-for="Id" />

            <label class="col-md-2 control-label">Document</label>
            <div class="col-md-10">
                <input class="form-control" type="file" asp-for="Document" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Document" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input id="save" name="save" type="submit" value="Upload" class="btn btn-default pull-right" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [Client side validation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/validation) section:

> You must have a view with the proper JavaScript script references in place for client side validation to work as you see here:
>
> ```
> <script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-2.2.0.min.js"></script>
>
> <script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.16.0/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
> <script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validation.unobtrusive/3.2.6/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js"></script>
> ```

Comment: Arg! I can't believe I missed that! You're never too old/experienced/etc to not RTFM. :)