# How to validate IFormFile property using validation attribute in ASP.NET Core MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, validation, asp.net-core

I'm using ASP.NET Core MVC and want to validate IFormFile property in model by validation attribute.

My model:

```cs
[Required(ErrorMessage = "Please upload an book image")]
public IFormFile BookImage { get; set; }
```

My cshtml file:

```html
<input asp-for="BookImage" type="file" accept="image/*"/>
<span asp-validation-for="BookImage" class="text-danger"></span>
```

But when NOT choose file and press submit button, the form still can submit. It doesn't require BookImage.
Why? And how to make IFormFile to be required? Thank you.

Comment: use this link I hope useful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46623147/aspnet-core-required-attribute-not-working-on-file-input

Comment: thank you, but it doesn't work for me :(

Comment: @dunghxh Have you correctly added the client side validation libraries?

Comment: @bolkay I've already added them. It works well for other properties except IFormFile

Comment: I don't know what's wrong but you can actually deal with that from the backend. E.g. `if(viewModel.BookImage==null){ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty,"Please upload image");return View());}` Something like that might work.

Comment: I've created a sample application which requires IFormFile as part of its properties and it works correctly without any issues. Could you please test that and compare it with your existing application? [Here](https://github.com/MoienTajik/RequiredFormFileTest) is the Github repo of the sample app.